# Library for NLP augmention

Tags: database, for-loop, nlp, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

I run code in pycharm and have error as below
Can I solve the problem by install library in anaconda?

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nlpaug'

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version (include BETA features) from github directly

```
pip install numpy git+https://github.com/makcedward/nlpaug.git
```

or install over conda

```
conda install -c makcedward nlpaug
```

or via pip

```
pip install nlpaug
```